# error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '{' token..but cant find?

Tags: c, function, syntax-error

I have the following C code with this function:

```
alist* createalist(int length){   //error occurs here
    struct alist *alist2 = malloc(sizeof(struct alist));
    alist2->size = length;
    alist2->data = calloc(2, sizeof(void *));
    alist2->data[length] = NULL;
    return alist2;
}
```

This is contained in a .c file. My .h file declares it like this:

```
alist* createalist(int length);
```

typedef of alist:

```
typedef struct alist {
  int current;
  int size;
  int increment_rate;
  void ** data;
} alist;
```

Of course I included my .h in my .c. This used to compile successfully, but now for weird reasons I always get the

```
error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '{' token
```

error at the beginning. Everything seems to be alright. I don't get it.

Comment: Can you share the code above it?

Comment: Looks like the code above it is the problem. You still have a discrepasncy between aliste* createalist in your header file and alist* createalist in your code.

Comment: well above is just the includes ( #include <stdio.h> ...)

Comment: @J.Wilson It might be a missing semicolon in your header file.

Comment: edited question was just a writing paste error @Biffen

Comment: There has to be more than that.  `alist` needs to be defined *somewhere*.

Comment: @Olaf I meant main function. Sorry about that. What I mean is he has to have some non-standart libs or some kind of struct or typedef for alist* somewhere in code prior to this part.

Comment: @Magisch: That's why everyone asks for a [mcve] and it already has 2 close-votes.

Comment: try `alist* createalist...` --> `struct alist* createalist`

Comment: `taille` member does not exist

Comment: Could not replicate, including `typedef`: https://ideone.com/E9bLJU

Comment: If you're attempting to translate your code when you post it here, then what you've posted is not what you compiled, and bug may be added/removed in the process.  Copy/paste the **exact** code you're compiling.  That will show us where the problem lies.  Better to see code in another language than code that isn't "real".

Answer (score 3):

Mostly a guess (by seeing the usage of `sizeof(struct alist)`), but it looks like

```
alist* createalist(int length){
```

should be

```
struct alist* createalist(int length){...
```

---

EDIT:

after the addition of the `typedef struct` part, I don't see any structure member named `taille`, which is being used in

```
alist2->taille = length;
```

Comment: Not sure why people would downvote. the missing struct is definately a problem in the code. @J.Wilson even if it wasn't directly the cause, you still need it.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `typedef` was added after the answer was posted, anyway.

Comment: @Magisch typedef and struct are named the same so it confuses hell out of some compilers try `typedef alist { } alist_d;`

Comment: @GRC I meant the struct in the function call.

Comment: @GRC and don't forget the `taille` thing...wondering is it a haloween special things. :P

Comment: @SouravGhosh a paste error again its size not "taille".sorry

Comment: @J.Wilson how about you just paste the entire content of your .c file now. According to your compiler its a syntax error most likely and we can't help you if you don't provide the entire code.

Comment: Yeah, it's a waste of people's time trying to diagnose your problem if you provide incomplete code _and_ keep making "paste errors".